# Solving Ordinary Differential Equations with variable coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having a tough time to solve the following Differential Equation as it is not a Cauchy-Euler Equation and hence cannot be solved easily, please help as much as you can:
$x^3y'' + 3x^2y' +2y = 2x$
Also, this equation can be written as:
$(x^3y')' +2y = 2x$

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: In order to make it an eigenvalue equation multiply by x^-2. Looks bad for a positive 1/x^2 term, because -y'' - y/x^2 is not bounded from below.